# Passing self as parameter

Tags: objective-c, object, pointers, parameters

I am fairly new at Objective C and may be confused since I am used to C++.  I am making an iphone game and what I want to do is have a class all enemies and heros "register" and "unregister" to.  I want to pass each individual instance of an enemy and hero to this singleton class and then add the object to a NSMutableArray and be able to call functions and change variables within each specific instance (by using a for-loop based on their registerIDs).  I am getting an error it expects a type (in damagedistributer.h") when I am trying to pass the pointer of an enemy object and looking online at forums no one seems to be answering this question. How could I make this work?  I don't want a copy of the object that is on the stack so when I change variables I don't lose those changes.  Thanks in advance. Here is some code:

DamageDistributer.h

```
@interface DamageDistributer : NSObject {

    GLuint enemyRegisterID;
    GLuint heroRegisterID;

    NSMutableArray *enemies;
    NSMutableArray *heros;
}

- (void)RegisterHero:(Player*)playerHero; //PROBLEM HERE
- (void)RegisterEnemy:(AbstractEnemy*)enemyUnit; //PROBLEM HERE 
- (void)Unregister:(GLuint)registerID type:(GLuint)typeOfEntity;

+ (DamageDistributer*)sharedDamageDistributer;
```

DamageDistributer.m

```
- (void)RegisterHero:(Player *)playerHero {

    [heros addObject:playerHero];
    playerHero.damageDistID = heroRegisterID;
    heroRegisterID++;
}

- (void)RegisterEnemy:(AbstractEnemy *)enemyUnit {

    [enemies addObject:enemyUnit];
    enemyUnit.damageDistID = enemyRegisterID;
    enemyRegisterID++;
}

- (void)Unregister:(GLuint)registerID type:(GLuint)typeOfEntity {

    if (typeOfEntity == hero) {
        [heros removeObjectAtIndex:registerID];
    }
    else {
        [enemies removeObjectAtIndex:registerID];
    }
}
```

And then this is the call from the Enemy Class

```
sharedDamageDistributer = [DamageDistributer sharedDamageDistributer];
[sharedDamageDistributer RegisterEnemy:self];
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Edited: 
Oh wow overlooked that... Thanks guys I was thinking it was more than that. One more question. Will the mutable array shift the indexes once an object is removed from the array so i will have to go decrement all the objects (registerIDs) after the one being removed? Or no it keeps the indexes where they are and it fills in the blanks? Or keeps adding to the end not shifting anything? Thanks again.

Comment: If the class calling self is of type AbstractEnemy, it's fine, don't worry about it.

Comment: Tangent: I believe the ObjC convention is `camelCase` for method names, not `PascalCase`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the header doesn't know about Player and AbstractEnemy. You can either import those 2 headers, or just add @class (forward declaration) which tells the compiler there's a class for that name. Then of course you import those headers within the implementation of DamageDistributer

```
    @class Player;
    @class AbstractEnemy;
    @interface DamageDistributer : NSObject {

        GLuint enemyRegisterID;
        GLuint heroRegisterID;

        NSMutableArray *enemies;
        NSMutableArray *heros;
    }

    - (void)RegisterHero:(Player*)playerHero; //PROBLEM HERE
    - (void)RegisterEnemy:(AbstractEnemy*)enemyUnit; //PROBLEM HERE 
    - (void)Unregister:(GLuint)registerID type:(GLuint)typeOfEntity;

    + (DamageDistributer*)sharedDamageDistributer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not recognizing your custom classes in the header.  Add declarations to your .h file, such as:

```
@class Player;
@class AbstractEnemy;
```

Answer (score 1):

In objective-C everything (with the exception of basic c types like int, strict, etc.) is on the heap. All objects are on the heap and use reference counting (like smart pointers) for memory management.

Your error looks unrelated to this though, and it could be you're just failing to `#import "Player.h"`